# How to configure azure webjob to run every 15 minute

Tags: azure, cron, azure-webjobs, webjob

Good afternoon, my friends, I would like to inform you that I am Brazilian so I would like to apologize for my English.

I have an azure webjob and want to set it to run every 15 minutes.

I'm deploying my webjob using Visual Studio and I already have my settings.job file. My problem is that when I set up to run every three minutes, it works perfectly, but when I set it to run every fifteen minutes, it works only minutes 0,15,30,45.

I hope you have managed to understand me

This is how my settings.job file is:

```
{ "schedule": "* */15 * * * *" }
```

Comment: Isn't 0, 15, 30, 45, ... every 15 minutes as you expected?

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have expressed myself badly, what I meant, is that it runs at "full" times, for example, 15:00 - 15:15 - 15:30 -: 15: 45. And what I want is for it to run regardless of the time, for example, 15:03 - 15:18.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The semantic of cron expressions is that they are absolute in term of time. So when you have `0 */15 * * * *`, it means run at exactly 0 minutes after the hour, 15 minutes after, etc... There is no way to make it start from an arbitrary time.

You wrote *when I set up to run every three minutes, it works perfectly*, but the behavior should be the same there: 0, 3, 6, 9, ...

As an aside, note that your cron expression is not quite correct. Instead of `* */15 * * * *`, it needs to be `0 */15 * * * *`. Otherwise, it will run every second for a whole minute, every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 7):

So a CRON expression is composed of six fields -> `{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day of the week}`

Thus, to run a job every 15 minutes, it should be something like -> `0 */15 * * * *`

Here's a reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs#cron-expressions

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you by the answer! But my problem is alredy solved!

Comment: That should be fine Miguel. Just want to show variations to everyone for reference purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8) expression as well, which I find it quite easier to understand:

```
public async static Task SomethingAsync(TimerTrigger("00:15:00", RunOnStartup = true, UseMonitor = true)] TimerInfo timer)
```

Where "00:15:00" is "every 15 minutes" as `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15).ToString()` says.

This requires you to use **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions** NuGet which you have to be careful to match your **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs** version.